# Can a long-running map operation on one partition delay processing on other partitions in Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming

I have a mapGroupsWithState function that I would like to add some additional functionality to based on the groupBy key. Roughly it would look like this:

```
 dataFrame
      .as[Log]
      .groupByKey(_.id)
      .mapGroupsWithState(GroupStateTimeout.NoTimeout())(processData)
      .writeStream
      .trigger(Trigger.ProcessingTime(s"$x seconds"))
      .outputMode(OutputMode.Update())
      .foreachBatch(postProcess _)
      .start()


  def processData(id: String, logs: Iterator[Log], oldState: GroupState[Checkpoint]): Array[Log] = {
    if (f(id)) {
        // long running operation
    }
    else {
      .
      .
      .
    }
  }
```

My dataframe is partitioned by the id field. I realize that since this `if()` operation is long running, it may delay the processing of other batches of data with an id that maps to the same partition. However, there was some concern brought up as to whether this long running operation could also delay the processing of data batches on other partitions. I'm not sure how Spark handles batches of data when taking the output of mapGroupsWithState and then passing that to forEachBatch; am I in danger of delaying data output on all partitions with this setup? It seems counterintuitive to me that delays on one partition could affect another, but I'd like to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

> `mapGroupsWithState` runs at *Executor* level.

This means parallel operations. An Executor Core is assigned to a Task servicing a given Partition for the duration of the processing of that Partition.

Assuming you have enough Executors and thus Cores, there should be no issue, but of course if you have 1 Executor with 1 Core only available to your App, then you would get an issue at Task level.